# How to retrieve FFMPEG (called from OpenCV) Python decoding error

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

While trying to read a video stream form an IP camera using:

```
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
(grabbed, frame) = stream.read()
```

The `grabbed` returns True while sometimes the frames are corrupted (probably due to high CPU load). An internal Opencv error like the following is showing on the terminal:

```
[h264 @ 0x25e99400] error while decoding MB 87 29, bytestream -5
```

Is there a way to catch this error? Please note that I tried the obvious `try:except` with `cv2.error` etc. In such case of corrupted frame it would be preferable to restart the connection to the camera.

Comment: Not an OpenCV error, that's [ffmpeg error log message](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/95e5396919b13a00264466b5d766f80f1a4f7fdc/libavcodec/h264_slice.c#L2664)... so nothing to catch there.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to catch this ffmpeg error from Python API?

Comment: I believe you can use `isOpened()` to check if the camera is corrupted. It allows you to skip the broken video and go on to the next one but the error message will still be printed. `if stream.isOpened():` then attempt to read a frame

Comment: Hi @nathancy, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, `isOpened()` is not a good option since the RTSP stream was already initialized and it will always return `True`. The problem occurs due to high CPU load during processing and not at initialization time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any cpp output/error can be retrieved from Python using [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer)

```
from wurlitzer import pipes
with pipes() as (out, err):
   <any call to cpp code>

c_error = err.read()
```

Comment: Did you figure out what caused the "error while decoding MB" error?

Comment: It can happen if you use UDP protocol and your network connection to the camera is slow.